# Intent with PreferenceScreen in preferences.xml

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferencescreen

My Google-Fu is failing this Android newbie today.

Does anybody know of a good example showing how to launch an intent from a PreferenceScreen?

Something like:

```
    <PreferenceScreen
        android:key="preference_some_new_layout"
        android:title="@string/pref_some_title">

            <intent android:action="????" /> 

    </PreferenceScreen>
```

I want to show a custom LinearLayout that allows me to set some semi-complex preferences.

What is the best way to go about this?

Thanks,
wTs

Comment: This isn't my answer, but it answers your original question, about how to launch an intent from a PreferenceScreen in xml: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3751306/582004

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used a custom dialog box before for a preference.  Is this sort of what you need?  [Here is an example from my open source app.](http://code.google.com/p/tippytipper/source/browse/trunk/Tippy%20Tipper/src/net/mandaria/tippytipper/preferences/DecimalPreference.java)

And [here is the XML to add the preference to a PreferenceScreen](http://code.google.com/p/tippytipper/source/browse/trunk/Tippy%20Tipper/res/xml/settings.xml).

```
<net.mandaria.tippytipper.preferences.DecimalPreference
                        android:key="exclude_tax"
                android:title="Tax Rate to Exclude"
                android:summary="The tax rate to exclude when calculating tip"
                android:dialogMessage="Tax Rate"
                android:defaultValue="0"
                android:dependency="enable_exclude_tax_rate"
                />
```

This will let you produce complex preferences in a DialogPreference (you might be able to swap this out if you don't need a Dialog, someone else will have to fill that in for you because I've never tried) that look like this:

[image]

Comment: I wrote a little more about it here: http://www.bryandenny.com/index.php/2010/05/25/what-i-learned-from-writing-my-first-android-application/ But basically you need to make sure you persist your values i.e.  mValue = getPersistedInt(mDefault); or persistInt(value + mMin);

Comment: Amazing examples about custom preferences, thanks Bryan I learn a lot :-D thanks for sharing code